# Webpack and React Image Not Found

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, flask, webpack

I have looked at [so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46999422/error-adding-image-with-react-and-webpack) [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52208817/how-to-render-images-with-webpack-react) [different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41775698/using-webpack-and-react-to-load-images) [resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582405/react-wont-load-local-images) ([some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42580130/display-images-in-react-using-jsx-without-import) [not](https://stackabuse.com/serving-static-files-with-flask/) [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45641827/unable-to-extract-image-file-uploaded-on-react-frontend-on-flask-backend?rq=1), and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52481728/loading-local-images-with-webpack) being the closest to my problem). None of them seem to solve my issue.

I'm brand new to both React and Webpack. I found [this tutorial](https://codeburst.io/creating-a-full-stack-web-application-with-python-npm-webpack-and-react-8925800503d9) and followed it to create a basic website.

However, I'm having issues displaying images. Instead of displaying the image, I get a "broken file" image and the console says `GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/public/images/smiley.png 404 (NOT FOUND)`

I have installed the Webpack image loader and I am using `require` in my React code. It looks like webpack is finding the image because if I change the name of the image I get an error like `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '../images/smiley.png'` which crashes the whole website instead of the 404 error.

This is my folder structure:

[image: folder structure]

When I run the project with `npm run watch` and `python server.py` (from `static` folder and `server` folders respectively), a `public` folder with `smiley.png` inside of it appears inside of the `dist` folder.

I have a hunch that the issue is that my Flask is configured in such a way that it does not respond the request because it thinks the `public` folder is off limits. But that's just a hunch, and I don't know how to fix it if that's the case.

My code can be found [here](https://github.com/Jadiker/image_issue_webpack_react_flask/tree/f9e0d1a8c318965c1bdc822dc5ea322deff30635). Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

Following my hunch, I added the following to my server.py:

```
@app.route("/public/<path:path>")
def get_public_file(path):
    print("getting something from public: {}".format(path))
    return send_from_directory("public", path)
```

But that also did not work - I am still getting a 404.

EDIT 2:

Thanks to @Joost, we found out that using `app = Flask(__name__, static_folder="../static", template_folder="../static")` puts the image correctly at `http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/images/smiley.png`.

However, this then causes Flask to not be able to figure out where `bundle.js` is, since it's located inside the `dist` folder.

Adding in

```
@app.route("/dist/<path:path>")
def get_dist_file(path):
    print("getting something from dist: {}".format(path)) # this ran
    return send_from_directory("dist", path)
```

to `server.py` did not help - I still get `GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/dist/bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (NOT FOUND)` in the inspector.

So now the trick is to figure out how to keep the smiley face served, and have flask serve the `bundle.js` file as well.

EDIT 3:

I just discovered a really sketchy way of getting it to work, so sketchy that I'm not even going to post it as an answer because I want something that's less sketchy.

Using @Joost's `app = Flask(__name__, static_folder="../static", template_folder="../static")` and adding the following to `server.py` worked.

```
@app.route('/<path:path>')
def static_file(path):
    print("getting static file {}".format(path))
    if path.startswith("public/"):
        path = "dist/" + path
        print("in public folder; path changed to: {}".format(path))
    return app.send_static_file(path)
```

The issue with this solution is that I really shouldn't be using `send_static_file` since it's extremely insecure, and that including an `if` statement like that seems prone to many errors. A different solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I kept overlooking where the app was running from, sorry about that.

By far the easiest solution is to set you static folder to a different folder:

`app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='../static')`

I just tried it, and this should work without a problem.

You can find your file here:

`http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/images/smiley.png`

Your bundle file will be here:

`http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/dist/bundle.js`

You're getting a template error because you don't have a template folder, which is normally called tempates. So make a subfolder called `templates` in your `server` folder. Then, don't specify the `template_folder` argument in the `app = Flask(..)` line, but keep it `app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='../static')`.

If, for some reason, you want to seperate your static from your public files and have a `/public` route as well, you might want to try the following approach:

```
@app.route("/public/<path:path>")
def get_public_file(path):
    full_path = os.path.join('../static/dist/public/', path)
    head, tail = os.path.split(full_path)
    return send_from_directory(head, tail)
```

You can then access the smiley in the `fullstack_template/static/dist/public/images/smiley.png` by going to `http://127.0.0.1:5000/public/images/smiley.png`.

Comment: What should I change in my code in order to fix this? I don't have any paths that start with `http://127.0.0.1:5000/` in my code

Comment: Also, all of those are giving me 404 not found error messages when I type them into my browser

Comment: In what folder are you running your app?

Comment: the server is run from the `server` folder (this is mentioned in the question as well)

Comment: This now works to put the smiley at `http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/images/smiley.png`, but the main website (found at `http://127.0.0.1:5000/`) now gives a `500 Internal Server Error` and does not load anything

Comment: More specifically, I am getting a `jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: index.html` error

Comment: using `app = Flask(__name__, static_folder="../static", template_folder="../static")` gives me a `GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/dist/bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (NOT FOUND)` error, which I think is actually the problem with the new solution

Comment: Okay, I agree that both those files are now in the correct place. I had to move index.html into the `templates` folder for it to be able to find it. `http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/images/smiley.png` does indeed have the smiley, but the webpage still shows `GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/public/images/smiley.png 404 (NOT FOUND)`. I believe this is because webpack stores the image inside its `dist` folder, and then expects Flask to pick it up from there, but it doesn't. (Here's [the github](https://github.com/Jadiker/image_issue_webpack_react_flask/tree/928cdd5b640ee66e0c1457d66bed1e0a6d26cb44))